# Grails: Incorrect exception className when using servlet filter

Tags: grails, servlet-filters

I have created a servlet filter, and now wherever exception is thrown - the cause always is the filter class.
I'm retrieving exception class in ErrorController using `request.exception`.
**Stacktrace**:
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
    at my.MyController$_closure4.doCall(**MyController.groovy:68**)
... 
    at my.MyFilter.doFilter(**MyFilter.groovy:38**)
    ...
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
I can't get real cause of exception:/

So why `request.exception.getClassName()` returns **MyFilter** instead of **MyController** ?

MyFilter:

```
@CompileStatic
```

class MyFilter implements Filter{

```
UrlMappingsHolder grailsUrlMappingsHolder
MyService myService

@Override
void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

}

@Override
void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    String url = ((HttpServletRequest)servletRequest).getServletPath()
    def urlInfo = grailsUrlMappingsHolder.match(url).getParameters()
    if (!myService.controllersToNotCheck.contains(urlInfo.controller) && !myService.sourcesExist()) {
        throw new NoEnvironmentException()
    }
    filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse)
}

@Override
void destroy() {

}
```

}

Comment: did you check line 68 in MyController.groovy?

Comment: @VinayPrajapati the problem is not in place, where exeption is thrown, but in ErrorController, where all errors are redirected. When I handle this exception, the code **request.exception.getClassName()** always returns "MyFilter"(instead of "MyController", in this case), and it doesn't matter in what class exeption was thrown actually

Comment: Hmm, try a getCause() on the exception?

Comment: Could you show us filter code?

Comment: @majkelo just added filter code

Comment: @railsdog getCause() returns instance or RuntimeException, but I need class, where this exception was thrown (in my case this is myController)
wat actually *request.exception.getClassName()* does - it parses stacktrace and finds this class - so this is what I need, but it returns wrong class:\

Comment: `request.exception.getClassName()` points to where the exception was thrown. In you case because it was initiated from the filter, it will return `MyFilter`. In your filter you can print the URI, when exception occurs, it will give you a good indication, what controller was called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys for trying to help.
The issue was the following:
Grails wraps exception using GrailsWrappedRuntimeException class; 
This one parse stacktrace, and looks for the last occurrense of file with .groovy extension. 
MyFilter is always the last groovy class in stacktrace (if read from the top to the bottom), thats why className is always MyFilter, so it hides information about controller or service where exception was thrown.
My solution was simple: I rewrote filter as a "MyFilter **.java**" :)